# Mini-PCIe Signal Voltage Levels

Tags: pcie

Can PERST, CLKREQ, WAKE#, and SMBUS operate at 1.8 V? What I am designing is a mini-PCIe slot compatible with a WWAN card, but this WWAN card can only operate at 1.8 V.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Per the mini-PCIe electromechanical specification, the sideband signals use the 3.3Vaux supply as there power source, and are therefore intended to be used with 3.3V signalling levels.

Indeed oer the DC specifications for these signals, the minimum high voltage is 2V for an input.

[image: DC Specification for 3.3V Logic Signalling]

So simply, no they will not work correctly with a 1.8V device. Fortunately there are many simple level shifting ICs which will allow interfacing between a 1.8V device and a 3.3V interface.